# Overloading Square Brackets Operator to Accept Value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a collection class. I want to overload the square brackets operator ([]) to provide access to elements in the collection.

```
int operator[](int i)
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

My problem is that I don't see how to write this so that I could use this operator to accept a value:

```
myClassInstance[0] = value;
```

I see no way to declare the square brackets operator with an additional argument (the value to assign to the element).

I know I can simply return int& and the caller can assign a value to that, but internally each element is stored in a different format than the one made public.

Is this even possible?

Comment: you need two operator[] (int) versions. a const version and the non-const version that you asked for. The original version should have const behind it ,for calling on a const object;

Comment: @Edwin: I saw your other comment. I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write an `int_proxy` class that is implicitly convertible to `int` and is assignable from `int`.  You'll need at least two member functions:

```
operator int();
int_proxy& operator=(int);
```

In this proxy class, store whatever information you need to be able to retrieve and set the value in the container.  Do the retrieval in the conversion operator and the assignment in the assignment operator.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the original int operator[] (int) should have an const modifier ,which allows it to be called on const objects.

Comment: Was thinking I could do this more simply than that. But it doesn't look like it. Thanks!

Comment: @Edwin: Is there any way to make it so that one may read a `const` object using `[]`, and both read and write a non-const object using the same operator?

Comment: @supercat: sorry ,I don't reallly understand what exactly you meant ,but in a proxy class you can do anything you like as long as you don't violate constness.  maybe you should post a separate question about it ,linking to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Return a reference to an object that has an operator = that can stuff the int where it needs to go. Look at the boolean vector trickery in STL for an example, if not necessarily a wonderfully exemplary example.

Answer (score 1):

write:

```
    int& operator[](int i)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
```